# Managing multi processes to do the same jobs in C

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

I write a code that some processes use an array, sort it and then print it. In fact What I would like to do is that each process should sort a line of integer numbers that main process gives to them and print them, then send them back to the main process. The algorithm works fine without process and forking. But when I add forking, some process cause printing or performing some instruction more than one time or more. Please let me know how to manage it.

Here is the code:

```
 if (N<=NumberOfLines)
    {
        PortionOfProcess=NumberOfLines/N;
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++)//making N process using fork
        {
            for (int j=0; j<PortionOfProcess; j++)//For using from function by a single process
            {
                int pointer=i*PortionOfProcess+j;//this points to the line for each process
                printf("poniter: %d . the i is %d, the j is: %d and the portionprocess is : %d\n",pointer,i,j,PortionOfProcess);

                fileopener(B_result,pointer);


                mypid=fork();
                if (mypid==0)//child
                {
                    ///////////do the sorting
                    for (int j=0 ; j<(y-1) ; j++)
                    {
                        for (int i=0 ; i<(y-1) ; i++)
                        {
                            if (B_result[i+1] < B_result[i])
                            {
                                t = B_result[i];
                                B_result[i] = B_result[i + 1];
                                B_result[i + 1] = t;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for (int j=0 ; j<y ; j++)
                    {
                        printf("SORTED %d \n",B_result[j]);
                    }
                //////////////////end sorting
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. As you print from multiple childs *with no child identification*, output from the childs will be randomly mixed. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Thanks for answering, what I would like to do is that each process should sort a line of integer numbers that main process gives to them and print them then send them back to the main process. So as you said I should put the print inside the child processes. Am I right?

Comment: You never *send data back* to the main process in your code. You need to use shared memory or pipes or Inter Process Communication functions for that. And explainations about that would be much too long for a SO answer :-( My advice is to google for shared memory or pipes, try them and then come back here with more precise questions.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Thanks a lot. However can you just tell me why there is some repetitive printing data in this code by now?

Comment: @SergeBallesta: In my opinion some process access a cells of array in the same time!

Comment: With fork, each process gets its own copy of the data, so each process access a different array, all initialized the the data of parent process at the time of fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am new in C programming. I write a code that some processes use an array, sort it and then print it. The algorithm works fine with out process and forking

Here is what `fork()` does: it creates an entire new copy of the process that, in most ways, is completely independent of the original. However, the original parent process does not wait for the children to finish. Nor has it any way of communicating with the children.

What you want to do is actually quite complex. The parent and child processes needs to create some sort of communications channel. This is most usually done by [creating a pipe](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/pipe.htm) between them. The child will then write to the pipe like a normal file and the parent will read from the pipe. The logic will look something like this:

```
create pipe
fork
if parent close write end of the pipe
if child close read end of pipe
```

The children then do their stuff and exit normally. The parent, however, has a load of files to read and it doesn't know which order to read them in. In your case the children are fairly simple, so you could probably just read each one in the order you create it, but you may also want to look at [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) so that you read the results in the order they are ready.

Finally, you need to call [wait or waitpid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) so that you get the return status of each child and you do not end up with [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) which is a possibility because with the parent blocking on input from various pipes, any mistake you make could lead to it waiting forever (or until killed).